# Do rvalue references allow implicit conversions?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++11, temporary, rvalue-reference

Is the following code legal?

```
std::string&& x = "hello world";
```

g++ 4.5.0 compiles this code without any problems.

Comment: Do you know of any interesting use case for this? I thought the only reason for named rvalues was for binding to special overloads.

Comment: @Inverse: Well, that's exactly why I was really asking, passing arguments to functions. It's just that, for the purpose of asking the question, I did not want to write and call a function ;) Technically speaking, there is no such thing as a named rvalue (except for the keywords `this` and `nullptr`). You probably meant a named rvalue *reference* -- like `x` in this example, which is an lvalue, not an rvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is discussed on usenet currently. See [Rvalue reference example in 8.5/3 correct or wrong?](http://groups.google.de/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/2b72ea155e039ac6?hl=de#).

It's not legal.

Comment: @Jerry that is a subbullet of "the reference shall be an rvalue reference and the initializer expression shall be an rvalue", which the string-literal does not satisfy.

Comment: @Jerry string literals are lvalues, like in C. See 5.1.1/1. Unlike plain ints, they refer to objects and need to convert to pointers. Thus, they indeed have the property of being an "storage locator value" (which lvalues that refer to objects are).

Comment: @Johannes: Yup -- I hadn't found 5.1.1/1, which clearly does say so. Thanks. That clearly makes the interpretation impossible.

Comment: I believe that they could also be rvalues, technically. But being an lvalue, i think, does fit more because it indicates the referred storage is static, instead of temporary. In C89, non-lvalue array expressions couldn't convert to pointers, so there the reason was very technical in nature. C99 lifts that restriction.

Comment: "It's not legal." -> Do you think this could still change during the standardization process? Because I'd really like it to be legal :)

Comment: Does the sad smiley imply that you would also like my example to be legal?

Comment: @Fred i don't really know. I've got too little experience with rvalue references to make a founded opinion. :(

Comment: Wait a minute, do you seriously expect me to believe you have never written a move constructor or something? ;)